# CouchDB: Filter by List of Account IDs and Sort By Date

Tags: couchdb

Trying to retrieve a list of events from a list of specific accounts (using account ids) and sort these events by date.

Here is my current map function:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc.doc_type == 'event' && doc.account_id) {
      emit([doc.date_start,doc.account_id],doc);
   }
}
```

This outputs the correct data when run in Futon for all accounts, however, I am unclear on how to construct my request query or whether I need to modify my map function to get this accomplished? All that matters is that the events are in one of the accounts specified and that the event dates are sorted in order (descending).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- do a query for each account, and merge the results on the client:

  ```
  function(doc) {
    if (doc.doc_type === 'event' && doc.account_id) {
      emit([doc.account_id, doc.date_start], 1);
    }
  }
  ```

  Query with (*properly url-encoded*) `?include_docs=true&startkey=["ACCOUNT_ID"]&endkey=["ACCOUNT_ID", {}]` for each value of `account_id`. The merging is fast and easy because the results are already sorted by date.
- do a single query, and sort the results on the client:

  ```
  function(doc) {
    if (doc.doc_type === 'event' && doc.account_id) {
      emit(doc.account_id, 1);
    }
  }
  ```

  Query with `?include_docs=true&keys=["ACCOUNT_ID1", "ACCOUNT_ID2", ...]`. Sorting will be slower because results are sorted by `account_id`.

Only tests will tell you what's the best option for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcello! Went ahead with option 1 because it is easy. :)